# Error while executing Phantomjs in AWS Lambda Java Function

Tags: java, linux, phantomjs, aws-lambda, illegalstateexception

I created and invoked AWS Lambda function using Eclipse for Crawling with the help of Phantomjs (Headless Browser) for Crawling. While executing the Lambda function, it's throwing an **illegal state exception error**. The executable file is located at **/var/task/phantomjs**. I tried even applying the **chmod** command for that executable file still it shows the same error. The code as follows

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
try {
    Process p = r.exec("chmod 755 /var/task/phantomjs");
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

DesiredCapabilities dCaps = new DesiredCapabilities();
dCaps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
dCaps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", false);      

dCaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,"/var/task/phantomjs");
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(dCaps);
```

The error is as follows:

```
The driver is not executable: /var/task/phantomjs: java.lang.IllegalStateException
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable: /var/task/phantomjs
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:534)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:140)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService.findPhantomJS(PhantomJSDriverService.java:245)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService.createDefaultService(PhantomJSDriverService.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:105)
    at com.amazonaws.lambda.rss.RSS.handleRequest(RSS.java:77)
    at com.amazonaws.lambda.rss.RSS.handleRequest(RSS.java:1)
```

It will be of great help if you can get me out with this issue, thanks in advance.

Comment: Phantomjs is a native executable.  When you package your Lambda where are you getting it from?  In a Linux environment,  can you run the `file` command on the executable you are packaging?

Comment: What's the output of int p.exitValue(); ?